# how to wrire into the contents of the registers in ADMV1013 up converter using arduino Due?

Tags: arduino-due, spi

There are nine registers inside and the contents of the registers can be changed to perform several operations. The link of the data-sheet is given here(Page 26). The write cycle sampling must be performed on the rising edge.
The 16 bits of the serial write data are shifted in, MSB to lower
sideband.
The link: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADMV1013.pdf

Comment: I do not understand what you are asking for. Especially "MSB to lower sideband" makes no sense for me. MSB and LSB have nothing to do with the lower or upper side band of the up converter. If you want to program the Due to transfer the data words to the registers of the convert, you could use the SPI library. It is a core library and always available in the IDE. It is documented on the Arduino page. One special note: The converter uses 1.8V input and output level. So you should use a level shifter to connect it to the Due.

Comment: https://www.arduino.cc/en/reference/SPI

Comment: Yes I am using a level translator to generate 1.8 V for the up converter. I am using the SPI.transfer() command to write into the registers but I could not understand how to change the contents of the registers .I mean when I am sending a specific data by SPI.transfer(data),will that data be stored in the registers???and also if we look into the data sheet of the up converter,you can see the timing diagram for the read and write is mentioned specifically.the changing of the MSB is for to enable  the read or write more if operation.